# What is the best way to store and access static table data?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

A real beginner here,

I am looking to have a table of static data with about 300 cells in it. (There will be 12 distinct tables in all)

The user would input two values, the first would indicate the row, and the second would point to the cell within that row, and I want my app to be able to read back the column heading for that row.

What is the best way to have this data stored in my app? Currently the data is in a spreadsheet.

The data looks like:

Index 0,Index 1,Index 2,Index 3 ,Index 4,Index 5,Index 6,Index 7,Index 8,Index 9

10,156,326,614,1261,1890,3639,5800,10253,20914

20,107,224,422,867,1299,2501,3986,7047,14374 ...etc.

Where the number at index zero is the name of the row (entered by user) and the numbers after that are the values also entered by the user.

I want the code to take the two numbers (row and value) and then return a string based on the column heading (shown here as index 0 - 9)

the last tricky bit is if the user enters a value that is in between the values give I want it to use the next highest value from the data. E.g. if in row "10" the user inputs 700 I want the code to return the index heading for 1261.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities are endless...

- In code as a static 2D array
- XML
- JSON
- Tab Delimited Text File
- Comma Delimited Text File
- PList
- etc.

All depends on your needs and wants.

On the CONs for each:

- Static 2D array may consume some memory every time the app runs...
- A file will involve some disk IO or processing requirements to read the values out of the file stored in the Bundle.

On the PROs for each:

- Data from the static array would be FAST...
- Updating data in a file could be done on-the-fly over the web.

You could write a simple routine to dump your spreadsheet into any of the above listed options, so I don't think that's a real serious consideration. It's mostly about what works best for you in terms of size of data and updatability/maintainability.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of using a PList with an array stored for each row, then have the code find the cell and based on its index, return a label for the 'column' heading. But I do like the idea of a static 2d array for the quickness and simplicity. The data will not change and if it does it will stay that way for years, so need to update it won't be a concern. So an array of arrays essentially is a static array? What is the best way to read in the data?

Comment: When you say "What is the best way to read in the data" what do you mean? Like how to convert your spreadsheet into code for an array?

Comment: Yeah, how can I best take a spreadsheet (can be saved in CSV) and then read it into multiple arrays. I can use \n to split up the CSV into rows and then "," to separate each row into cells. But I don't know how to get Xcode to read the file in to these arrays.

Comment: I added more detail to my original post above. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I ended up using an array of arrays, and once I wrapped my head around how to access the nested values, it worked very well.